# Teacher Edition vs Solution Key?

Tags: textbooks

I have a copy of the "Teacher Edition" of a pre-calc textbook my students are using. It's similar to their text, but the pages are reduced a bit to offer room for answers and some commentary.

Now I see a "Solution Key" for this same title. The page count is less than half of the text. Unfortunately, there's no preview feature. I'd have been happy to see 2 random pages from a chapter.

What, exactly can I expect from this book? Is it a summary of answers, or is there a comprehensive set of worked out problems? I realize this invites the potential for "How would we know? We don't even know the book title?" But I'm trusting that, as in many areas of life, there's a meaning to the words used, and I'm hoping a member here will have experience with the printed "Teacher edition" vs "Solution Key."

Update - Indeed, Daniel's answer was correct. The solution key had the answers worked out as I hoped. It was published by the same publisher, but had no author credited, for what that's worth.

Comment: Often these "solution keys" are products of a third party not endorsed by the publisher. Also a "Teacher Edition" is usually an edition that the publisher can give away for free in order to sell copies of their usual textbook. In some cases they are marked with (the totally non-legally binding) words (NOT FOR RESALE). These free editions are usually given away to professors and schools in the hopes of the schools might use their typically very overpriced books (I have never seen any affordably priced book ever give away free instructor editions, though maybe someone has an example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Former comment, now an answer: Usually these have worked out-solutions, expanding on any answer key in the instructor test, and usually written by a 3rd party author. A secondary clue to this point is the length of it (half the original text). But it could possibly go either way.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I placed the order, and will edit in remarks on my question to confirm what this book looks like.